# <img src> tag doesn't work properly (MVC, HTML)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Here is my code (part of the Index.cshtml file):

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Warunki wypozyczenia</h2>
        <p>
            Kazdego wypozyczajacego obowiazuja jednakowe zasady dotyczace wypozyczonych ksiazek. <br />Najwazniejsze z nich:
            <ol>
                <li>Nie jedz z ksiazka.</li>
                <li>Myj rece przed czytaniem.</li>
                <li>Nie kap sie z ksiazka.</li>
                <li>Jesli jestes strazakiem, zostaw ksiazke w bazie przed akcja ratunkowa.</li>
            </ol>
        </p>
        <img src="~\Content\DataTables\images\rules.png" alt="Rules" />
    </div>
```

This is project structer:

[image]

In the code, when I mouseover it, image shows up:

[image]

On the site there is error:

[image]

I have tried refactoring path to this file but nothing helped.

Any ideas?

Comment: give exact location of your image location

Comment: The folder structure image shows its in `/Views/Home` - is it also in `Content/DataTables/images`? Its also a `jpg` file, not a `png` file

Comment: Sorry, I was tired and didn't notice I was giving wrong folder location on the image I have posted. Location was properly, because I had rules.png in DataTables/images. Mistake was using "\" instead of "/". But thanks for impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you using `\` instead of `/`?

correct way is

```
<img src="~/Content/DataTables/images/rules.png" alt="Rules" />
```

Comment: Okay, that's... Ugh. Thanks a lot Nitin. 30 hours straigth with Visual Studio and you forget html path format is different then used in VS ;d

Answer (score 3):

Change this line of code

```
<img src="~\Content\DataTables\images\rules.png" alt="Rules" />
```

to

```
<img src="~\Content\DataTables\images\rules.jpg" alt="Rules" />
```

You need to consider the extension in you image.
"png", "jpg"

hope that helps

Comment: That was "slashes" problem. Take a look at Nitin Sawant answer. You are right about path, but I didn't mention (sorry, I am tired) I have this file with .png extension in DataTables\images\